# front matter ignored on blog posts

Tags: jekyll

I'm making a blog with jekyll that uses an index.html page with links to blog posts, as you see below in the first code sample. The default layout referred to in the front matter is a typical layout file with css styling by Twitter bootstrap included. However, when I click a link to a blog post in index.html, the blogpost is displaying (i.e. the url changes, the blog post content is displayed), however, the front-matter from the blogpost is being ignored, or at least it's appearing that way since none of the css styling is working on the blog post. For example, the css for the Twitter bootstrap navigation bar only shows on the home page, not the blog post.

Can you explain why this might be happening?

index.html

```
---
layout: default
---

{% for post in paginator.posts %}

<div class="row-fluid">
  <!-- <div class="span12"> -->
    <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
    <h4>{{ post.date | date_to_long_string }}</h4>
    <p>
      <a href="{{ post.url }}">Read Post</a>
    </p>
 <!--  </div> -->
</div>

{% endfor %}
```

2013-10-15-lorem-ipsum-blog-post

```
---
title: Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet
layout: default
---

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse elemen\
tum leo non felis porttitor vulputate. Nulla ipsum quam, auctor ut hendreri\
t quis, tincidunt eu metus. Quisque ipsum tellus, semper a tempus quis, int\
erdum vel magna. Cras a nisl diam, in accumsan augue. Pellentesque varius n\
ibh eu diam tempor rhoncus.
```

_layouts/default.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>{{ site.name }}</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="{{ site.description }}">
     <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

 <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".na\
v-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </a>
          <a class="brand" href="#">{{ site.name }}</a>
          <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
               <li class="active"><a href="/about">About</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

 <div class="container">

 <div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="col-lg-9 col-sm-8">
    {{ content }}
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4">
    {% include sidebar.html %}
  </div>
</div>

   </div> <!-- container -->

 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post the layout default.html

Comment: @MadhurAhuja I updated the OP with the default.html. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your layout file is just a relative file, I would suggest you add the paths of your CSS and javascript from the root. For example

```
 <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
```

should become

```
 <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <script src="/js/respond.min.js"></script>
```